# Calculate mouse coordinates, after an image was scaled

Tags: image, language-agnostic, coordinates, scale, mouseclick-event

Assume I have an Image with dimensions 800 pixels width by 500 pixels height.
Assume I scale this Image with some algorithm to dimensions 100 pixels width by 900 pixels height and assume I got a mouse click at x:50, y:35 with X:0, y:0 as pixel in the top-left corner.
How to calculate, where the mouse click would be in the original Image, if it wasn't scaled?

Is there an easy formula do calculate this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS:

Mouse X-Coord in the original image = Mouse-X-Coord / (new_width / original_width); 
Mouse Y-Coord in the original image = Mouse-Y-Coord / (new_height / original_height)

Comment: That seems to easy to be true, thanks man! :D

Comment: well, you did ask for an "easy" formula. :) By way of explanation, this just re-establishes your mouse coordinates proportionally to the changed dimensions of the surface.